# no input file specified error in codignator

Tags: codeigniter, frameworks

Hi I am using CodeIgniter 1.7.3 framework in my project. I have given URL for a link like this

`base_url/index.php/admin/featuredlink/flid/11`

, and when I click on this link I am getting an error like this

`no input file specified`.

But when I change that link to `base_url/index.php?admin/featuredlink/flid/11` it works fine.

In my local system this link [`base_url/index.php/admin/featuredlink/flid/11` ] works fine.

Why is this link [`base_url/index.php/admin/featuredlink/flid/11`] not working?

How do I get this link to work? If any one knows, please reply.

Comment: You should add which web server you are using and a copy of the parts where the url is rewrote in .htaccess if applicable.

Comment: I use domainspricedright.com server

Comment: Have you tried different settings for your `uri_protocol` in your config?

Comment: i tried with different settings of uri_protocol and also change $config['index_page'] = "index.php?"; and  $config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';  but still problem exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure first that you are changing your `$config['base_url']` from your local development address to your remote development address. This is located in `application/config/config.php`.

Also make sure you're using the right URL Helper function for your needs. Here's what I mean:

The `site_url()` function/method will always include index.php in your URIs. Here's an example using the site name `http://example.com` as your website's domain.

`<?php echo site_url('home') ?>` will turn into `http://example.com/index.php/home`

While `base_url()` function/method will always exclude index.php unless you include it. Here's an example using the site name `http://example.com` as your website's domain.

`<?php echo base_url('home') ?>` will turn into `http://example.com/home`

and

`<?php echo base_url('index.php/home') ?>` will turn into `http://example.com/index.php/home`

Keep in mind that using these functions/methods are only effective AFTER you have properly modified your `.htaccess` file. Follow the link below to remove index.php from your URIs by modifying your `.htaccess` file.

```
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
```

Keep in mind too that this can vary from host to host in the way that it needs to be formatted, so follow up on that with your hosting service. Most usually have guides that show you how to configure this properly.

Here is the link that shows you a more in-depth difference between the `site_url()` and `base_url()` functions.

```
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html
```

I hope this helps!